# Append text if validation fails but not repeat every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've this HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="country form-control" required="required" name="fos_user_registration_form[country]" id="fos_user_registration_form_country">
        ....
    </select>
</div>
```

Then in my jQuery code I have a condition, if it fails, then I append some HTML to the SELECT element as follow:

```
$(".country").on('change', function() {
    country = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $.get(Routing.generate('states', {country_id: country})).success(function(data) {
        if (data.message === "") {
            $('.state').empty().append('<option value="-1">Choose state</option>');
            $.each(data.entities, function(i, d) {
                $('.state').append('<option value="' + d.id + '">' + d.name + '</option>');
            });
            $('.state').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('.country').after('<span class="help-block">' + data.message + '</span>');
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (status == '500') {
            message = "No connection";
        }
    });
});
```

This output something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="country form-control" required="required" name="fos_user_registration_form[country]" id="fos_user_registration_form_country">
        ....
    </select>
    <span class="help-block">Some text goes here</span>
</div>
```

But any time I change the select and condition fails `<span>` is repeat once and once producing this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="country form-control" required="required" name="fos_user_registration_form[country]" id="fos_user_registration_form_country">
        ....
    </select>
    <span class="help-block">Some text goes here</span>
    <span class="help-block">Some text goes here</span>
    <span class="help-block">Some text goes here</span>
    <span class="help-block">Some text goes here</span>
    <span class="help-block">Some text goes here</span>
</div>
```

When should be just one time, what I need to do to fix that?

Also how I add a class to `<div class="form-group">` since this is not the only DIV with that class and applying to `$('.form-group')` will add to all the DIVs on the page, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to remove the span first if already exists

```
$(this).next('.help-block').remove()
```

To add class to the current parent div only, use parent

```
$(this).parent('.form-group').addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: The first approach works but changing `$(this)` for `$('.country')` do not know why is not working with `this`, but the second one, the one for add the class is not working, any other idea on this tough?

Comment: I changed from `.parent()` to `.closest()` and it works as I want, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, to select only this particular "form-group" you will need to add another type of identifier to the markup. This can either be another class name, or perhaps an id, like so:

```
<div class="form-group" id="form-group-country">
    ...
</div>
```

Then you'd be able to single out this `<div>` easily in jQuery like this:

```
// Store the form-group wrapper for the states <select>
var $formGroupCountry = $('#form-group-country');
```

To answer your question about only adding the span once, you will want to keep some kind of flag to know that the error has already been added to the DOM. This should work:

```
var hasErrorBeenAdded = false;
$(".country").on('change', function() {
    country = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $.get(Routing.generate('states', {country_id: country})).success(function(data) {
        if (data.message === "") {
            $('.state').empty().append('<option value="-1">Choose state</option>');
            $.each(data.entities, function(i, d) {
                $('.state').append('<option value="' + d.id + '">' + d.name + '</option>');
            });
            $('.state').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else if($('.country .help-block').length==0 && !hasErrorBeenAdded) {
            $('.country').after('<span class="help-block">' + data.message + '</span>');
            hasErrorBeenAdded = true;
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (status == '500') {
            message = "No connection";
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why I should add a `id` for each `<div class="form-group">...</div>`? This is not the idea, since what about if I have 10 or more? Will be crazy write code for each one, I tough

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply a flag for keeping track. something like this

```
var flag = 0;//declare globally
if(... && flag == 0){
    //your scripts
    flag++;
}
```